# Mouseover/Mouseleave: 3rd image positioning and toggling on and off

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this JSFiddle, I'm trying to do a simple mouseover an image1, it changes to image2 with an icon image appearing also that contains a link to click on.  I have trouble making this little icon image(+link) disappear on mouse off and instead it just keeps adding more of the same icon image(+link) with each mouseover(I know it's because I have .after() in jquery), but is there something to just do a simply mouseover/mouseleave?

Is there also a way to position this icon image using px anywhere you want around the main image1/2 on the page to appear?

http://jsfiddle.net/KpYnD/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.normalClassName').addClass('.normalClassName:hover').mouseover(function(){
$(this).after('<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" /></a><img src="http://www.quarktet.com/Icon-small.jpg">')

});

 });
```

Comment: why do you put the 'addclass' before 'mouseover' here?

Comment: I was trying to access the hover of the class normalClassName since it doesn't exist in the HTMl document and only in the css

Comment: hover class exists when you hover an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

**EDIT:** Updated this jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/KpYnD/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="normalClassName">
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="http://www.quarktet.com/Icon-small.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.normalClassName {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: transparent url('http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/vector-stylish-weather-icons-by-bartosz-kaszubowski/png/256x256/sun.rays.medium.png') top left no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}

.normalClassName a {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
}

.normalClassName:hover {
     background: transparent url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/256/Status-security-medium-icon.png') top left no-repeat;
}

.normalClassName:hover a {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: The icon image (the diamond) didn't disappear on mouseleave.How do you make that icon (diamond image) disappear on mouseleave?

Comment: It's leaving for me, do you mean once you leave the padlock, or the icon itself?